# Intel Quick Sync, Cant encode From .YUV to mp4 (4K video)

Tags: video-encoding, yuv

I have started  learning intel Quick Sync recently,so i am not competent yet , I can encode 1080p videos, and I have one 4K video(.YUV) but I can not encode it as 4K(.mp4).The thing is I can encode it to 1080p or to any other lower resolutions, but not 4K.

This is the 4k .mp4 file specs(the broken one after encoding), which  media player cant open it:

[image]

Also the format of the video showing as AVC, which I used .mp4 as output.

This is the command I am using for encoding:

sample_encode.exe h264 -i video_output.yuv -o result.mp4 -w 3840 -h 2160 -dstw 3840 -dsth 2160 -sw

thanks.

Comment: How do you know it's not an issue with Media Player? Try playing the file using [VLC player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/). Are you sure `sample_encode.exe` supports MP4 format? Shouldn't it be `sample_encode.exe h264 -i video_output.yuv -o result.264 -w 3840 -h 2160 -dstw 3840 -dsth 2160 -sw` (encoding H.264 elementary stream)?

Comment: This is not the issue with media player because, other encoded videos can be played.(i have tried multiple video players but didnt work.) Also , I am not sure about .264 output format. i have tried .mp4 for other videos and it worked. Should it be .264?

Comment: I have tested it with `Encoding Sample Version 20.1.0` (and `Intel Media SDK 2020 R1`) in Windows 10, and your exact command is working in my machine (the 4K video is playable). The MP4 extension is working, but it's not an MP4 file. `.264` is just a convention for raw H.264 stream file. If it's not the player and not the extension, it's probably related to the versions. I suggest you to test it using latest version of VLC (not other players), because VLC has it's own set of video codecs.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was the file extension as you mentioned(should be .264 not .mp4), now i can play my 4K videos as well. The odd thing about the encoding, when i  encoded to .mp4 in lower resolutions they were playable(which should not have been), and when i tried on 4k i faced this problem.